# Populate array with values that are greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate an array with values that are in the range `dataRange` that are `>0` but it is not functioning properly

```
Dim kRow As Variant, cell As Range, dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = ws.Range("AE4", ws.Range("AE4").End(xlDown))

ReDim kRow(0)
For Each cell In dataRange
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        kRow(UBound(kRow)) = cell.Value
        ReDim Preserve kRow(UBound(kRow) + 1)
    End If
Next cell
ReDim Preserve kRow(UBound(kRow) - 1)
```

It doesn't appear to be finding anything `>0` as `kRow` is empty when looking at the locals window

What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure? Test it with `Debug.Print UBound(kRow)` as last statement what is the result? The code is working fine for me, no issues. Are you sure that `cell.Value` is numeric and not text?

Comment: Code worked for me as well, though I used a different range declaration. If your range declaration works, the rest of the code should too.

Comment: To verify that `ws.Range("AE4").End(xlDown)` is really what you want please manually select AE4 and press ctrl+down (arrow down). The now selected cell is the last cell of `dataRange` starting from AE4. In case you meant the last cell in column AE instead, then use `Set dataRange = ws.Range("A4", ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code has problem only if it does not find any values in AE4.

Then `ReDim Preserve kRow(UBound(kRow) - 1)` this one throws an error.

In general put some values in column `A` and give it a try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim kRow As Variant, cell As Range, dataRange As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set dataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A4", ActiveSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown))

    ReDim kRow(0)
    For Each cell In dataRange
        If cell.Value > 0 Then
            kRow(UBound(kRow)) = cell.Value
            ReDim Preserve kRow(UBound(kRow) + 1)
        End If
    Next cell

    For i = LBound(kRow) To UBound(kRow)
        Debug.Print kRow(i)
    Next i

    'ReDim Preserve kRow(UBound(kRow) - 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you have in `dataRange` it might be quicker to load into a temporary array and process, rather then loop cells on the worksheet. Also `ReDim Preserve` is an expensive operation, so better to avoid if possible.

The below code stores `dataRange` in a temp array, loops temp array to find matches and stores row index number, re-sizes `kRow` to suit then copies over the matching values

```
Sub PopulateArray()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim temparr() As Variant, kRow() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, InstanceCount As Long
    Dim RwIndexList As String, Rw As Variant

    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("AE4", ws.Range("AE4").End(xlDown))

    'store dataRange in 1D array for processing
    temparr = Application.Transpose(dataRange.Value)

    'loop to determine # of instances > 0
    For i = LBound(temparr) To UBound(temparr)

        If temparr(i) > 0 Then RwIndexList = RwIndexList & "_" & i

    Next i

    'only process if matches found
    If Not RwIndexList = vbNullString Then

        'determine # of matches
        InstanceCount = Len(RwIndexList) - Len(Replace(RwIndexList, "_", ""))

        'resize kRow to match # of instances > 0
        ReDim kRow(1 To InstanceCount)

        'initialize kRow counter
        i = 1

        'copy matching rows to kRow
        For Each Rw In Split(Mid(RwIndexList, 2), "_")

            kRow(i) = temparr(Rw)
            i = i + 1

        Next Rw

    End If

End Sub
```

An alternate option which would only require a single array and 1 loop would be to use `Application.Index` to slice the array to filter out non-matching rows; however this only works on 2D arrays so you'd be left with a 2D array as your output, not sure if that's an option for you?

```
Sub PopulateArray_Alternative()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, dataRange As Range
    Dim kRow() As Variant, i As Long, RwIndexList As String

    Set ws = Sheet1 'change to suit
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("AE4", ws.Range("AE4").End(xlDown))

    'store dataRange in 2D array for processing
    kRow = dataRange.Value

    'store matching rows in index list
    For i = LBound(kRow) To UBound(kRow)

        If kRow(i, 1) > 0 Then RwIndexList = RwIndexList & "_" & i

    Next i

    'only process if matches found
    If Not RwIndexList = vbNullString Then

        'slice array to filter non-matching rows
        kRow = Application.Index(kRow, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(RwIndexList, 2), "_")), 0)

    End If

End Sub
```

As @Peh mentions you might also want to add some data validation to the test criteria unless you know that all your data is numeric.